# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed

Tags: python, windows, ssl, https

I am using python 2.7.10

```
request = urllib2.Request(url, data=urllib.urlencode(params))
f = urllib2.urlopen(request))
```

cause the following exception:

```
urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
```

URL is a website hosted in IIS with our organizations ca sign cert.
I have already imported the root cert into **windows certificate manager** and I am able to open the URL in browser securely **without** encountering message like "There is a problem with this website’s security certificate."

How do I go about troubleshooting this issue?
I do not want to disable the SSL verification

Comment: Is this a internet site ? can you check with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ if there is not a missing intermediate certificate.

Comment: this is an intranet site. the network do not have access to the internet

Comment: Use a wellknown search engine to look for, at a wild guess, _requests python verify ca cert_ and AFAICT the top result tells you how to pass your own CA cert to verify certificates.

Comment: *" I have already imported the root cert into windows certificate manager ..."* - python 2.7.10 (and requests) do not use this but use its own CA store.

Comment: is there a way to use windows certificate manager instead? ssl.get_default_verify_paths() returns non existent path. /usr/local/ssl/cert.pem. I am using windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you access URL through browser, you browser becomes client and server becomes on which Web site is hosted. Now, since you have imported CA certificate for browser, that's why web site is opening without error in browser.

Now, when you open same website from your python script, client becomes your python script and it is not aware of this CA certificate. Python script do not use the **Windows Certificate** Store, so you will have to specify a **CA certificate** against which the certificate verification will be done.

So, you have tell explicitly to script regarding CA certificate which can as follow:

```
urllib2.urlopen("https://dinesh.com", cafile="test_cert.pem")
```

You can find the documentation here: [urllib2.urlopen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen).

**UPDATE**

Snippet from the above link:

> The optional **`cafile`** and **`capath`** parameters specify a set of
>   trusted CA certificates for HTTPS requests. **`cafile`** should point
>   to a single file containing a bundle of CA certificates, whereas
>   **`capath`** should point to a directory of hashed certificate files. More information can be found in
>   **[ssl.SSLContext.load_verify_locations()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_verify_locations)**.

Comment: I just assumed python will use the windows cert store. Is there a way to make it use windows cert store instead?

Comment: @TanWeiLian: no, it is currently not possible to use the windows cert store.