# SSLHandshakeError - Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, phpstorm

I am working on a simple project on PhpStorm and installed GAE plugin and SDK. Running a server and show the project works, but when I try to deploy my application I get this kind of error: (This is a PHP project)

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:/Users/asim/AppData/Local/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/appcfg.py" update .
10:08 AM Application: gtmdocx; version: None
10:08 AM Host: appengine.google.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/asim/AppData/Local/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/appcfg.py", line 133, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:/Users/asim/AppData/Local/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/appcfg.py", line 129, in run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "C:\Users\asim\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5518, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\asim\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5509, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "C:\Users\asim\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2969, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "C:\Users\asim\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 5165, in __call__
    return method()
  File "C:\Users\asim\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3897, in Update
    self._UpdateWithParsedAppYaml(appyaml, self.basepath)
  File "C:\Users\asim\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3918, in _UpdateWithParsedAppYaml
    updatecheck.CheckForUpdates()
  File "C:\Users\asim\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\sdk_update_checker.py", line 245, in CheckForUpdates
    runtime=runtime))
  File "C:\Users\asim\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc_httplib2.py", line 246, in Send
    url, method=method, body=payload, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\asim\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\httplib2\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1626, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "C:\Users\asim\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\httplib2\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1368, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "C:\Users\asim\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\httplib2\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1288, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\asim\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\httplib2\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1082, in connect
    raise SSLHandshakeError(e)
httplib2.SSLHandshakeError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've tried to uninstall and upgrade Python, now I'm using 2.7.9 but still this error wont remove. I tried also removing `cacerts.txt` but still no luck still this problem

```
ttplib2.SSLHandshakeError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)
```

I hope anyone has encountered this problem before and can help me with this.

Here is my App.yaml file:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
service: default
application: gtmdocx

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main.php
  login: admin
```

Comment: Read [ssl-certificate-verify-failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45408850/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify-failed)

Comment: I am also effected. Did you find any workaround? Seems like the issue the happened when I upgraded sdk. If you have any old version of sdk then it should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it working. Using PHPstorm IDE for deploying don't work, but using gcloud in command line works perfectly for deploying. Maby PHPstorm adds some config or parameters when deploying but i used the command line and it worked like charm

```
 gcloud app deploy app.yaml --project <project name> --promote --quiet
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

The traceback indicates the failure happens when trying to check for SDK updates, so you *should* be able to work around it by using `appcfg.py`'s `--skip_sdk_update_check` option.

I'm not using the PHP SDK, but I found a similar failure in the SDK upgrade check for the python development server, my solution for that could be applicable in your case as well. See [Google App Engine SSL Certificate Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43221963/google-app-engine-ssl-certificate-error/43233424#43233424).

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading httplib2 fixed to me!

```
sudo pip2 install --upgrade httplib2 -t /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/
```

Comment: `sudo pip2` is in general a bad idea. Use `pip2 install --user` is much safer.

Comment: Replying to @shouldsee's comment: in general yes, but this answer uses pip's `-t` flag to install into a specific target directory, in this case the directory being used by Google App Engine's libraries, so adding `--user` is not appropriate in this particular instance.  `pip install --upgrade httplib2 -t /usr/local/google_appengine/lib/httplib2` worked for me, and should see me through to 30 August 2020 when Google plan to disable `appcfg` and I'll have to add a billing card to the account for `gcloud` to work. (Apps that have not been recently updated with appcfg may already refuse updates.)

Comment: You are right I totally ignored the `-t`.  This command seems for MacOS which is something I dont use at all.

Answer (score 0):

If it is really a SSL handshake error than check to see if machine that you are using to access is behind a firewall. If you are than you will have a problem you might have to ask you network guys to open network up. alternatively you can try to get on to network that is not behind firewall. I might be wrong but I have been in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Scene is very clear. Google want you be moved to a premature version of Google cloud SDK CLI tool, for which even documentation is still half way. There are still basic features pending on Google Cloud SDK cli tool. Testing patience.

What you can do now is flush current GAE version 57/58 and install a old version of GAE launcher. I am using version 49. [Download Link](https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/featured/GoogleAppEngine-1.9.49.msi)