# SSL verification error in python

Tags: python, ssl

I am using the slackClient library to create a slack bot but I get ssl verification failed error when I use api.call() method of slack client. I was facing the same issue while using pip install but that got resolved by using --trusted-host. Is there some configuration in python required to access machine certs?

I have already imported the root cert into windows certificate manager and I am able to open the URL in browser securely without encountering message like "There is a problem with this website’s security certificate". 
I do not want to disable the SSL verification

I referred to the answers given at 
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45408850/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify-failed)

but slack client library calls urllib3 internally and I am not able to specify ca-file for it.

Is there a way to resolve this issue and configure python to use machine certs directly?

Comment: Does it happen even after setting the `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` env variable?

Comment: hi, I cannot see the requests_ca_bundle env variable could you plz describe how to set it in windows 10. I can access the certificates on my machine using certmgr.msc at run only so I don't know the location of my certificates to set the path. the certificates are installed in internal database so plz guide me as to how to set this variable.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can export it (`certmgr.msc` gives you a `Copy to file` option for each certificate, in the details tab), and then you can set `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` to point to the location of the saved certificate. And here's [how to set environment variables in windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10)

Comment: I have set the path but its still not working gives the same error again

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be to downgrade websocket-client.

Try the following: 
`pip3 install websocket-client==0.47.0`

Source: [this comment on issue](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient/issues/334#issuecomment-404663576)